# Ajax form onsubmit stop refresh

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have one page lets call it "X.php" that i use that calls another page "Y.php" with the xmlhttp.open() function.

At the moment i have a form in page Y.php, and i would like to prevent it from refreshing because once i click on the submit button, my form dissapear.

I tryed with Jquery 'event.preventDefault()' in page X.php but nevertheless it didnt work.

Does anyone know a solution?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo "    <h2>Update your personal settings</h2>

            <form action='' id='target' method='POST'>
                Surname: <input type=text name='lid_voornaam' value='".$row['lid_voornaam']."'><br/>
                Name: <input type=text name='lid_naam' value='".$row['lid_naam']."'><br/>
                Email: <input type=text name='lid_email' value='".$row['lid_email']."'><br/>    
                <input type='submit' value='Whatever' id='test1'/> 
            </form>";
    }
```

Java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#test1").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Comment: you forgot to post the javascript

Comment: my bad, i added the JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form tag. Add `onSubmit="return false;`

```
<form action='' id='target' method='POST' onSubmit="return false;>
   Surname: <input type=text name='lid_voornaam' value='".$row['lid_voornaam']."'><br/>
   Name: <input type=text name='lid_naam' value='".$row['lid_naam']."'><br/>
   Email: <input type=text name='lid_email' value='".$row['lid_email']."'><br/>    
   <input type='submit' value='Whatever' id='test1'/> 
</form>
```

As @andrew mentions. Your php script will generate multiple `<form>` tags which will all have the same id `id='target'`. This can cause problems on your page as that isnt valid html

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that the javascript you posted should work actually.

But if this is your actual code I suspect it fails because all of the submit buttons on all forms have `id='test1'` and id should be unique

Try like this:

```
$i=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo "    <h2>Update your personal settings</h2>

            <form action='' id='target."$i++".' method='POST'>
                Surname: <input type=text name='lid_voornaam' value='".$row['lid_voornaam']."'><br/>
                Name: <input type=text name='lid_naam' value='".$row['lid_naam']."'><br/>
                Email: <input type=text name='lid_email' value='".$row['lid_email']."'><br/>    
                <input type='submit' value='Whatever' id='test1'/> 
            </form>";
    }
```

and

```
 $("form").submit(function(event){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('target')[1];
    alert('form ' +id+ ' clicked');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: i thank you for your help andrew, but unfortunately every form has an unique ID. i will try to use a return false and try to put a function before the return false is being called.